# What do you call this type of guitar?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, instruments

Does anybody mind mentioning to me what this type of guitar is called? A pedal lap steel guitar maybe?

Man this thing has a magical sound!

Comment: Hardly *pedal* - there's not one in sight. Hardly *lap* - it's played like a standard guitar, not on one's lap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are all resonator guitars.  The bridge bears on a spun metal cone inside the body of the guitar that projects the sound (similar to how the head of a banjo works).

The guitarists in the second and third videos are playing with slides.

There is such a thing as a resonator lap steel, but it has the action set so high as to be only playable with a slide (unplayable by fretting with fingers):

A pedal steel is an entirely different beast, also only playable with a slide (a.k.a. bar, steel, etc.), but built into a stand with pedals that bend individual strings:

Comment: See also Nobro and National guitars.

Comment: Dzień dobry, @ToddWilcox! Perhaps you mean **[Dobro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobro)**?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you put some active EMG into that thing?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - **D**obro brings up lots of resonator guitars! Typo..?

Comment: Of course I meant Dobro

Comment: @NeilMeyer - probably wouldn't work - look at the number of strings. EMGs have 6 pole pieces.

Comment: I saw that Asher, makers of lap steel guitars, has 8-string guitars with EMG pickups.

Comment: The Dopyera brothers worked for National (the metal-bodied instruments are usually Nationals), then made their own company (**DO**pyera **BRO**thers), so the style of instrument has been called Dobro, but then, the electric Bass was called a Fender bass for a while. Bluegrassers sometimes say **TIFKAD** (The Instrument Formerly Known As Dobro).